# How to write after the end of the already initialized struct?

Tags: c

I have a struct initialized on a stack, and i want to write data in memory right after the struct and make a pointer inside a struct point to that data.
I know it is achievable on the stack/heap with uninitialized structure using malloc(sizeof(struct) + additional size) or alloca(). but can i perform initialization of a data after the struct is already initialized on the stack? and can i perform this initialization inside a initializator function?

Simple example:

```
struct TEST {
    wchar_t* itest;
};

void init_struct(struct TEST* test) {

    // point to the end of the struct
    char* walk_ptr = (char*)test + sizeof(test);
    test->itest = (wchar_t*)walk_ptr;
    
    // initialize data after the struct
    ...
}

int main(void) {
    
    struct TEST test;
    init_struct(&test);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: FWIW, that doesn't sound to me like something you would want to do.

Comment: You have no guarantee about what memory is in the stack after `test` - or whether you are even allowed to access it. So no, this is not possible that way

Comment: Can you do *FAM* (flexible array member)? See [C11 6.7.2.1](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1)p18

Comment: @pmg yep, i can, in theory, or use struct hack. but the question is about pointer in struct rather than array

Comment: "I have a struct initialized on a stack" and it contains a pointer variable. What is that pointer variable pointing to? With the shown code I would consider it as not initialised, especially not to anything legally allocated. Not a problem, because you do overwrite, but you do overwrite with some extremely fishy pointer arithmetic. What makes you think that it yields a pointer ot memory which you are allowed to write to? You do not actually write there in the shown code, but the comment implies that you want to. The question you ask is "how to write?" but I really want to to ask "Whether?".

Comment: So a) please distinguish between initialising the struct and initialising the memory the pointer points to b) please distinguish between initialising memory and allocating memore legally, which should be done BEFORE c) show in your [mre] anything which might allow you to write beyond the struct

Comment: If you say `struct TEST test[2];` and then `init_struct(&test[0]);` you can guarantee yourself `sizeof(struct TEST)` worth of extra bytes after `test[0]`.  If you need more than that you can use `struct TEST test[3];`.  (Not at all sure this is a path towards your desired result, though.)

Comment: *and i want to write data in memory right after the struct and make a pointer inside a struct point to that data*  No, you do **not** "want" to do that - that's nothing but undefined behavior.  In most implementations you'd be overwriting the stack.

Comment: You also handle (or not handle) the difference of `char*` and `wchar_t*` in a much too relaxed way for my taste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by embedding the structure inside another structure to reserve memory for the extra data:

```
int main(void)
{
    struct { struct TEST test; wchar_t data[NumberOfElements]; } S;
    init_struct(&S.test);
    …
}
```

However, the code in `init_struct` adds an incorrect size, `sizeof(test)`, to the pointer. You likely wanted to add `sizeof (struct Test)`, or, equivalently, `sizeof *test`, since you want to get past the `struct TEST` that `test` points to, not past a `struct TEST *` that `test` is.

However, even adding the correct size of the structure would not guarantee strictly conforming C code, since C implementations may insert padding between structure members. Properly we would add the offset of the `data` member. To do that, we nwould eed to give the structure a tag and then either make the structure definition visible to `init_struct` or pass the offset to `init_struct`. However, it is easier just to pass the address of the extra data:

```
void init_struct(struct TEST *test, wchar_t *data)
{
    test->itest = data;
}


int main(void)
{
    struct { struct TEST test; wchar_t data[NumberOfElements]; } S;
    init_struct(&S.test, S.data);
    …
}
```

Of course, a pointer can point anywhere, and there is no apparent reason the data should be immediate after the structure, so we can disconnect them:

```
int main(void)
{
    struct TEST test;
    wchar_t data[NumberOfElements];
    init_struct(&test, data);
    …
}
```